# Java: Objects that always have the same content?

Tags: java

I want to desrcibe my question with an example:

**Base.java:**

```
public class Base {

    //NO annotations
    public AnyClass anyObj;

    public Base(){}
}
```

**DerivedOne .java:**

```
public class DerivedOne extends Base{

    @SomeAnnotionsOne
    public AnyClass anyObjWithAnnotations;

    public DerivedOne (AnyClass anyObj){
        this.anyObj = anyObj;
        anyObjWithAnnotations = this.anyObj;
    }
}
```

**DerivedTwo.java:**

```
public class DerivedTwo extends Base {

    //These annoations differ from  @SomeAnnotionsOne
    @SomeAnnotionsTwo
    public AnyClass anyObjWithAnnotations;

    public Derived_Two(AnyClass anyObj){
      this.anyObj = anyObj;
      anyObjWithAnnotations = this.anyObj;
    }
}
```

So i just want `anyObjWithAnnotations` always be equal to `anyObj`.

**Example main:**

```
public static void main(String[] args){
   DerivedOne derivedObj = new DerivedOne(new AnyClass());
   derivedObj.anyObj = null;

   if(derivedObj.anyObjWithAnnotations == null){
      System.out.println("anyObjWithAnnotations : is null");
   }  
}
```

Nothing is printed. `anyObj` is `null`, `anyObjWithAnnotations` isn't.

**My Question:**

Is it possible that `anyObj` is always the same as `anyObjWithAnnotations`??

So even if i set one of them to `null` or create a new instance of `AnyClass` with `new` the other variable should have the same new content.

**EDIT:**

Changed whole example to clarify the problem.

Comment: `myObj1 = myObj2`?? Why would you want to have two two different objects with the exact same value?

Comment: you can use a same reference for both the object.

Comment: @luk2302 this doesn't work for me.. `myObj2: is null` is never printed .. it's a very special case with XML annotations: myObj1 is defined in a Base class and i need it in a derived Class

Comment: Where in `Derived_One` (please follow the Java naming conventions) is `anyObj` defined? You don't show the definition.

Comment: @Lew corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below code, where i am creating object 1 time only and then assign its reference into second object. In this way if a value is changed in one object, in example t1, it will be reflected into t2 as well.

```
    class Test {
    private int val;

    public Test(int val) {
        this.val = val;
    }

    public int getVal() {
        return val;
    }

    public void setVal(int val) {
        this.val = val;
    }
}
public class TestSame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t1 = new Test(10);
        Test t2=t1;
        System.out.println(t1.getVal());
        System.out.println(t2.getVal());

        t1.setVal(20);

        System.out.println(t1.getVal());
        System.out.println(t2.getVal());

    }
}
```

O/P :-

```
10
10
20
20
```

You can also check that both t1 and t2 has same hashcode value

```
  System.out.println("t1 hashcode "+ t1.hashCode());
    System.out.println("t2 hashcode "+ t2.hashCode());
```

Comment: this works fine unitl you set `myObj1` to `null`.. `myObj2` wont change at this point.. `myObj2: is null` is never printed

Comment: yup, when you are doing this, you are not supposed to change the reference, you should always use getter and setter to modify the state of the object.

Comment: I changed my example. Could you tell me if this is possible? If yes, how can i achieve it? Thanks

Comment: This is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need a singleton.

```
public class Singleton {
    private int val = 0;

    public void setVal(int val) {
        this.val = val;
    }
    public static final Singleton INSTANCE = new Singleton();

    private Singleton() { }

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
Singleton s1 = Singleton.getInstance();
Singleton s2 = Singleton.getInstance();

s1.setVal(42);
```

If singleton is too much for your case you can use approach:

```
Object obj1 = new Object();
final Object obj2 = obj1;
```

since `obj2` is final reference - you will not be able to change(reassign) it. So, `obj2` and `obj1` will refer the same Object instance. But it is possible to reassign `obj1` reference. If you set `final` both `obj1` and `obj2` - you'll get exactly what you want.

```
final Object obj1 = new Object();
final Object obj2 = obj1;
```

Comment: singleton pattern wont help in my case. To your second suggestion: `myObj2: is null` is never printed.. if `myObj1` is `null`, `myObj2` should be too!

Comment: It will be null. You can not change references after first assignment. but if you will assign: `final Object obj1 = null` - it will be null

Comment: seems you do not understand a singleton usage: if you will setVal(null) -  it will change in 'both' objects

Comment: I redesigned my question. I hope you understand my problem better now.